# Getting cart not found error even when the cart is present

Tags: spartacus-storefront

We are using Spartacus 1.4.2 and in production environment we are getting a "Cart not found." message frequently.

1. This happens for both logged in and guest customers.
2. We found a github link which is similar to our problem
   https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/issues/4622
3. We would like to know what was the fix done for this.
4. This can appear on any page while browsing.
5. We believe it has something to do with the MultiCartService.

Following are the requests for which the error occured.

For logged in user:

```
{
   "_index": "flb-2020.07.02",
   "_type": "flb_type",
   "_id": "123456789",
   "_version": 1,
   "_score": null,
   "_source": {
      "@fb_timestamp": "2020-07-02T05:46:02.304Z",
      "log": "{\"origin\":\"access-log\",\"timeMillis\":1593668762304,\"thread\":\"hybrisHTTP61\",\"contextMap\":{\"remoteHost\":\"0.0.0.1\",\"remoteUser\":null,\"requestLine\":\"GET /rest/v2/store/users/user123/carts/1000144077?fields=DEFAULT,potentialProductPromotions,appliedProductPromotions(FULL),deliveryAddress(FULL),deliveryMode,potentialOrderPromotions,appliedOrderPromotions(FULL),entries(totalPrice(formattedValue),product(images(FULL),stock(FULL),baseOptions(selected(priceData(FULL)))),basePrice(formattedValue),updateable),totalPrice(formattedValue),totalItems,formattedTotal(FULL),totalPriceWithTax(formattedValue),totalDiscounts(value,formattedValue),subTotal(formattedValue),deliveryItemsQuantity,deliveryCost(FULL),totalTax(FULL),pickupItemsQuantity,net,appliedVouchers,productDiscounts(formattedValue),user,warrantyInfo(DEFAULT,productReferences(target(code,baseOptions(selected(categories(code))),name,price(formattedValue),url)))&lang=en&curr=USD HTTP/1.1\",\"statusCode\":400,\"bytesSent\":186,\"processMillis\":5,\"commitMillis\":5,\"connectionStatus\":\"-\"}}\n",
      "stream": "stdout",
      "time": "2020-07-02T05:46:02.304776447Z",
      "logs": {
         "origin": "access-log",
         "timeMillis": 1593668762304,
         "thread": "hybrisHTTP61",
         "contextMap": {
            "remoteHost": "0.0.0.1",
            "remoteUser": null,
            "requestLine": "GET /rest/v2/store/users/user123/carts/1000144077?fields=DEFAULT,potentialProductPromotions,appliedProductPromotions(FULL),deliveryAddress(FULL),deliveryMode,potentialOrderPromotions,appliedOrderPromotions(FULL),entries(totalPrice(formattedValue),product(images(FULL),stock(FULL),baseOptions(selected(priceData(FULL)))),basePrice(formattedValue),updateable),totalPrice(formattedValue),totalItems,formattedTotal(FULL),totalPriceWithTax(formattedValue),totalDiscounts(value,formattedValue),subTotal(formattedValue),deliveryItemsQuantity,deliveryCost(FULL),totalTax(FULL),pickupItemsQuantity,net,appliedVouchers,productDiscounts(formattedValue),user,warrantyInfo(DEFAULT,productReferences(target(code,baseOptions(selected(categories(code))),name,price(formattedValue),url)))&lang=en_CA&curr=CAD HTTP/1.1",
            "statusCode": 400,
            "bytesSent": 186,
            "processMillis": 5,
            "commitMillis": 5,
            "connectionStatus": "-"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

For anonymous user.

```
{
  "_index": "flb-2020.07.02",
  "_type": "flb_type",
  "_id": "56789023345354",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "@fb_timestamp": "2020-07-02T06:21:06.485Z",
    "log": "{\"origin\":\"access-log\",\"timeMillis\":1593670866485,\"thread\":\"hybrisHTTP12\",\"contextMap\":{\"remoteHost\":\"10.245.1.7\",\"remoteUser\":null,\"requestLine\":\"GET /rest/v2/store/users/anonymous/carts/112233445566?fields=DEFAULT,potentialProductPromotions,appliedProductPromotions(FULL),deliveryAddress(FULL),deliveryMode,potentialOrderPromotions,appliedOrderPromotions(FULL),entries(totalPrice(formattedValue),product(images(FULL),stock(FULL),baseOptions(selected(priceData(FULL)))),basePrice(formattedValue),updateable),totalPrice(formattedValue),totalItems,formattedTotal(FULL),totalPriceWithTax(formattedValue),totalDiscounts(value,formattedValue),subTotal(formattedValue),deliveryItemsQuantity,deliveryCost(FULL),totalTax(FULL),pickupItemsQuantity,net,appliedVouchers,productDiscounts(formattedValue),user,warrantyInfo(DEFAULT,productReferences(target(code,baseOptions(selected(categories(code))),name,price(formattedValue),url)))&lang=en_US&curr=USD HTTP/1.1\",\"statusCode\":400,\"bytesSent\":209,\"processMillis\":4,\"commitMillis\":4,\"connectionStatus\":\"-\"}}\n",
    "stream": "stdout",
    "time": "2020-07-02T06:21:06.485316768Z",
    "logs": {
      "origin": "access-log",
      "timeMillis": 1593670866485,
      "thread": "hybrisHTTP12",
      "contextMap": {
        "remoteHost": "0.0.0.1",
        "remoteUser": null,
        "requestLine": "GET /rest/v2/store/users/anonymous/carts/112233445566?fields=DEFAULT,potentialProductPromotions,appliedProductPromotions(FULL),deliveryAddress(FULL),deliveryMode,potentialOrderPromotions,appliedOrderPromotions(FULL),entries(totalPrice(formattedValue),product(images(FULL),stock(FULL),baseOptions(selected(priceData(FULL)))),basePrice(formattedValue),updateable),totalPrice(formattedValue),totalItems,formattedTotal(FULL),totalPriceWithTax(formattedValue),totalDiscounts(value,formattedValue),subTotal(formattedValue),deliveryItemsQuantity,deliveryCost(FULL),totalTax(FULL),pickupItemsQuantity,net,appliedVouchers,productDiscounts(formattedValue),user,warrantyInfo(DEFAULT,productReferences(target(code,baseOptions(selected(categories(code))),name,price(formattedValue),url)))&lang=en&curr=USD HTTP/1.1",
        "statusCode": 400,
        "bytesSent": 209,
        "processMillis": 4,
        "commitMillis": 4,
        "connectionStatus": "-"
      }
    }
    }}
```

We are getting 400 status for these requests.

Hybris(1905) console log:

```
de.hybris.platform.commercewebservicescommons.errors.exceptions.CartException: Cart not found.
    at de.hybris.platform.commercewebservicescommons.strategies.impl.DefaultCartLoaderStrategy.loadUserCart(DefaultCartLoaderStrategy.java:124)
    at de.hybris.platform.commercewebservicescommons.strategies.impl.DefaultCartLoaderStrategy.loadCart(DefaultCartLoaderStrategy.java:87)
    at de.hybris.platform.ycommercewebservices.v2.filter.CartMatchingFilter.doFilterInternal(CartMatchingFilter.java:42)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:299)
    at de.hybris.platform.ycommercewebservices.filter.SessionCurrencyFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionCurrencyFilter.java:43)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:299)
    at de.hybris.platform.ycommercewebservices.filter.SessionLanguageFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionLanguageFilter.java:43)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:299)
    at de.hybris.platform.ycommercewebservices.filter.Europe1AttributesFilter.doFilterInternal(Europe1AttributesFilter.java:43)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:299)
    at de.hybris.platform.ycommercewebservices.filter.ConsentFilter.doFilterInternal(ConsentFilter.java:59)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:299)
    at de.hybris.platform.ycommercewebservices.v2.filter.UserMatchingFilter.doFilterInternal(UserMatchingFilter.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:299)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:176)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilter(ChannelProcessingFilter.java:157)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:299)
    at de.hybris.platform.ycommercewebservices.v2.filter.BaseSiteMatchingFilter.doFilterInternal(BaseSiteMatchingFilter.java:65)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:299)
    at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.WebAppMediaFilter.doFilter(WebAppMediaFilter.java:129)
    at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:299)
    at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.PolyglotPersistenceCallbackFilter.doFilter(PolyglotPersistenceCallbackFilter.java:45)
    at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:299)
    at de.hybris.platform.webservicescommons.filter.RestSessionFilter.doFilter(RestSessionFilter.java:39)
    at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:299)
    at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.Log4JFilter.doFilter(Log4JFilter.java:44)
    at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:299)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:299)
    at de.hybris.platform.webservicescommons.filter.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:33)
    at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:299)
    at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain.processStandardFilterChain(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:207)
    at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain.doFilterInternal(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:184)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:112)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at de.hybris.platform.webservicescommons.filter.SessionHidingFilter.doFilter(SessionHidingFilter.java:34)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.ShallowEtagHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ShallowEtagHeaderFilter.java:108)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.XSSFilter.processPatternsAndDoFilter(XSSFilter.java:358)
    at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.XSSFilter.doFilter(XSSFilter.java:306)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:543)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:747)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
    at de.hybris.tomcat.StoreJvmRouteAsContextParameterValve.invoke(StoreJvmRouteAsContextParameterValve.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:615)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:818)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1627)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The link you posted shows our testing showed the issue as fixed in later version. The issue should have been fixed in https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/issues/5647 and as mentioned we do not see it in later versions. If it’s possible we recommend upgrading to at least 1.5.
Before that, I would ask for more details. When you see an error, does the cart exists in the backend? What is the error log in the Hybris console? What are the steps that lead to this error?

Comment: Yes, the cart exists in the backend when I see this error. I have attached the Hybris console log in the ticket. Regarding steps to reproduce this issue, unfortunately this issue is very random and I couldn't figure out a pattern when it happens.

Comment: In my case - wrong user was signed to the card. Found solution through debug .